# std::variant 'attempting to reference a deleted function'

Tags: c++, std-variant

When trying to compile I get the error: `Error C2280 'std::variant<Tree::Position<int>,Tree::Position<std::string>,Tree::Position<double>,Tree::Position<bool>>::variant(const std::variant<Tree::Position<int>,Tree::Position<std::string>,Tree::Position<double>,Tree::Position<bool>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function`

I have a Tree class with a template sub-class Position. When using the load function of the Tree class, an instance of the Position class is added to the Tree's `treePositionList`. Also in the constructor function of the Position class an instance of the Position class is added to its `childenList`.  I think the problem is related to the adding of an instance to those lists, though I do not understand what goes wrong exactly.

```
template <typename E>
class Node {
private:
    string column;
    E element;
public:
    Node(E el, string col) { element = el; column = col;}
};

class Tree {
public:
    template <typename E>
    class Position {
    private:
        typedef variant<Position<int>, Position<string>, Position<double>, Position<bool>> Position_ManyTypes;
        typedef list<Position_ManyTypes> PositionList;

        Node<E>* node;
        PositionList childrenList;
    public:
        Position(Tree* tree, const E element, const string column, const Json::Value &children); 
        Position(Position<E>& position);

        ~Position();

        Position<E>& operator=(const Position<E> &position);
    friend class Tree;
    };

    typedef variant<Position<int>, Position<string>, Position<double>, Position<bool>> Position_ManyTypes;

    typedef list<Position_ManyTypes> PositionList;
    Tree() {}

    bool load(string filename);
private:
    PositionList treePositionList;
};

bool Tree::load(string filename) {
    ifstream rules_file(filename, ifstream::in);
    Json::Value rules;
    rules_file >> rules;
    rules_file.close();

    Position<string> root_position = Position<string>(this, "string123", "string456", rules["children"]);
    treePositionList.push_back(root_position);
    return true;
}

template <typename E>
Tree::Position<E>::Position(Tree::Position<E>& position) {
    node = position.node;
    childrenList = position.childrenList;
}

template <typename E>
Tree::Position<E>& Tree::Position<E>::operator=(const Tree::Position<E>& position) {
    if (this != &position) {
        delete node;
        node = position.node;
        childrenList = position.childrenList;
    }
    return *this;
}

template <typename E>
Tree::Position<E>::~Position() {
    delete node;
}

template <typename E>
Tree::Position<E>::Position(Tree* tree, const E el, const string col, const Json::Value &children) {
    node = new Node<E>(el, col);

    Position<string> pos = Position<string>(tree, "string123", "string456", children[0]["children"]);
    childrenList.push_back(pos);
}
```

Comment: I see the likely reason for the compilation error, however the shown code fails to meet all requirements for a [mre], as explained in the [help]; and it's been my experience that, too often, there is a different underlying cause that was not visible because of the code that's not shown, and too often after spending some time constructing an answer, it turned to to be a waste of time because of that. Please [edit] your question and include a self-contained code sample that anyone can cut/paste ***exactly as shown*** and reproduce the same compilation error. See [ask] for more information.

Comment: Your Position template lacks a copy constructor, so the variant will also lack a copy constructor. It looks like your `Position(Position<E>&)` can be upgraded to a copy constructor by adding`const`.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thank you very much. I've been looking over it for hours and I completely missed that.

Comment: "attempting to reference a deleted function" is the clue. The copy constructor was deleted. Why would a variant delete its copy constructor? [Copy constructor. This constructor is defined as deleted unless `std::is_copy_constructible_v<T_i>` is true for all `T_i` in `Types....`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/variant)